# How to display data in Accelerated Mobile Pages(AMP) from firebase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firebase, accelerated-mobile-page

I am create AMP Pages in my web project, I need to display data from firebase in AMP pages.
I use php and JavaScript to display data from firebase in web application.

Answer (score 0):

`Amp pages` are meant to be cache by google which means you need to server-render the pages as they will get crawled automatically by google bot.

SO, hit the firebase api from php / curl and render the data in php itself and produce AMP pages.

If you render template on client using java-script there are chances your amp may not get cached by google completely.

Comment: did you mean i have to create every AMP page programatically generate and save to my host directory ???   i have a lots of (business , products ) pages that i have to display in AMP  page structure is same but content may different in every page.  my other question is how to zomato works on AMP ???  it has many AMP pages with dynamic content  how they are working ???

Comment: see this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753477/how-to-display-dynamic-data-in-accelerated-mobile-pagesamp-from-firebase

Comment: AMP can only cache static pages , and iframes. Ajax calls are not supported i guess at the moment. Please link the zomato page you are talking about.

Comment: @atulquest93 zomato demo page.. please open this in mobile view https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.zomato.com/melbourne/roasting-warehouse-north-melbourne%3Famp%3D1

Comment: There no ajax call or any fire-base call ... the page is static html. Its serer rendered completely and html is cached by google.

Comment: If you navigate .. it will now load their mobile webapp and load data over ajax calls.. like https://www.zomato.com/melbourne/roasting-warehouse-north-melbourne/book  .. but, the amp page is static server generated.